# Facebook Open Graph started working wrongly when Liking the page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

So I have a blog: www.elnacional.com.uy

Each article has it's open graph meta tags, so when someone Likes the article, a title, picture and description are posted on facebook.

But suddenly it started working wrongly, now when u like the page u just get the Link to be posted on facebook, not the description nor the title nor the picture.

And I have no idea what's going on because nothing was changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use the debugger to troubleshoot your problems.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.elnacional.com.uy%2Fjugadores%2Fperalta-hablo-de-lo-que-se-viene-en-el-apertura%2F

This shows the following error:

> Object at URL 'http://www.elnacional.com.uy/jugadores/peralta-hablo-de-lo-que-se-viene-en-el-apertura/' is invalid because the configured 'og:type' of 'news' is invalid.

The "news" type for "og:type" isn't a valid type according to the [documentation here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#types).

This is why it doesn't know what to do with your title, image and description.

I suggest using the type `article` as it is documented as

> article - Use article for any URL that represents transient content -
>   such as a news article, blog post, photo, video, etc.

Comment: awesome. I had no idea a debugger existed. And googling would come up with too many irrelevant results about my issue. Shouldve googled something simplier. Thanks a lot sorry for the trouble

Comment: No trouble!  I'm glad to help :)

Answer (score -1):

The meta tags should be in the head, maybe that's why it isn't working :)

Comment: So they are, my bad. They look fine to me, but the url linter isn't detecting them. I dont know what's wrong, sorry.

Comment: The linter is picking up all of the meta tags.  It just doesn't know what to do with the images, because the og:type doesn't exist.